# Kivy Image Widget - module object is not callable

Tags: python, pycharm, kivy

Trying to add an image widget to GridLayout but I am receiving a not callable error.  I have reviewed samples online but seems to be causing error for me.  I'm sure its something simple but I am new to kivy and Python.

```
faceImage = Image(source='Event_Faces/David_Johns.jpg')
        self.inside2.add_widget(faceImage)
```

ERROR:

```
File "C:/Users/thoma/PycharmProjects/FacesApp/Main.py", line 62, in __init__
     faceImage = Image(source='Event_Faces/David_Johns.jpg')
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What does your `import` statement look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue was related to me importing Pil Image and kivy Image and that was causing conflict.